# Statistical methods to compare spatial maps

Tags: r, spatial

I would like to compare 4 radon flux maps (Bq m-2 s-1) generated using different methods. All of the maps use same projection and have same resolution. I am having trouble finding statistical method(s) which i could use for comparing the maps and analyse regions where they agree well and regions where the difference is large. I would be thankful for any ideas/suggestions that I can have a look at for further study.

My final  goal is to merge all these maps together and create a new map and run some simulations for the final map. Can i just take mean of the respective cell values to make the new map. Is it a correct way?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

And off course, a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)


e = extent(1, 1+(5*1), 1, 1 + (5*1)) 
r1 = raster(e) 
res(r1)=c(1,1) 
set.seed(1)
r1[] = runif(5*5) 
plot(r1, main='map1') 

e = extent(1, 1+(5*1), 1, 1 + (5*1)) 
r2 = raster(e) 
res(r2)=c(1,1) 
set.seed(2)
r2[] = runif(5*5) 
plot(r2, main='map2')

e = extent(1, 1+(5*1), 1, 1 + (5*1)) 
r3 = raster(e) 
res(r3)=c(1,1) 
set.seed(3)
r3[] = runif(5*5) 
plot(r3, main='map3')


e = extent(1, 1+(5*1), 1, 1 + (5*1)) 
r4 = raster(e) 
res(r4)=c(1,1) 
set.seed(4)
r4[] = runif(5*5) 
plot(r4, main='map4')
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into spatially local correlation analysis?